# Simplest path for custom media type in Spring HATEOAS?

Tags: java, spring-hateoas

I currently have a HAL output that looks like this:

```json
{
    "id": "00023687-7a6d-429f-a9d5-a900b1af4d27",
    "property1": "value",
    "property2": "value",
    "_links" : {
      "self" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/service/api/items/00023687-7a6d-429f-a9d5-a900b1af4d27"
      },
      "abandon" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/service/api/items/00023687-7a6d-429f-a9d5-a900b1af4d27/abandon"
      }
  }
}
```

My organization prefers an output like this:

```json
{
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/service/api/items/00023687-7a6d-429f-a9d5-a900b1af4d27",
    "id": "00023687-7a6d-429f-a9d5-a900b1af4d27",
    "template": "http://localhost:8080/service/api/items/{id}",
    "schema": "http://example.com/schemas/items",
    "property1": "value",
    "property2": "value",
    "operations": [
        "rel": "abandon",
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/service/api/items/00023687-7a6d-429f-a9d5-a900b1af4d27/abandon",
        "method": "POST"
    ]
}
```

What will be the easiest path to render the output like that?

Do I need to go through the full implementation of a Jackson Module like is done below?

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/bf62d037cdb21483aa8e1dcec78165e82777d30d/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/mediatype/collectionjson/Jackson2CollectionJsonModule.java

Or, is there a shortcut method I can take to customize just the way the "self" relation is rendered and the rest of the links should be rendered to make them appears in an "operations" array instead of an object map?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Spring HATEOAS documentation contains [how to register a custom media type](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#mediatypes.custom). It's worth studying the implementations in the [mediatype package](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/tree/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/mediatype). The way is quite complicated.

If your motivation to use a custom media type is just the `method` field, you can check the media type [HAL-FORMS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#mediatypes.hal-forms).

The HAL-FORMS template can be either included in the response JSON body (inline resource), or not (separate resource). See [Spring HATEOAS - Hypermedia APIs with Spring 42:48](https://youtu.be/o4cc6KzNrpI?t=2568)